# Is is correct to compare t-statistics of different pairs of cointegrated timeseries?

Tags: regression, least-squares, cointegration, finance, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am testing for cointegration all the pairs from a set of 100 stocks. I run an Ordinary Least Square Regression on each pair and then I test for the existence of unit roots in the residuals. I am using  the ADF test with no trend and no intercept.
I am surprised that I found a big amount of pairs which the test on the residual rejected the null hypothesis of having a unit root, with p-values smaller than 0.01.
Can I use the Dick Fuller Statistic to rank those pairs? All the series have the same length.

Comment: It depends on what you are after. ADF test tells you how strongly you can reject the null hypothesis of a unit root, so if you want to rank the pairs by how strongly you reject the null, then sure.

Comment: I would think that as long as you validated the Gaussian Assumptions underlying the t test you should be good to go. I am currently expanding the ECM solution to deal with Gaussian Assumptions/Violations using AUTOBOX a time series / econometric package I helped develop.

Comment: @Akavall, I want to rank them by how strong they are cointegrated. As the pairs are very different, have different statistical caracteristics, i was not sure if a DF t-statistic for one pair could be comparable with a t-statistic for another pair.

Comment: @IrishStat, thank you. I agree with you that validating the Gaussian Assumptions is a very important matter in dealing with the t statistic. How should I validate those assumptions?

Comment: @Thiago Please see my answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/how-can-i-check-if-my-time-series-data-is-zero-mean-stationary-and-independent

Comment: @Thiago In addition the errors from the model should have an auto-correlation function suggesting randomness.

Comment: @IrishStat Thank you for your valuable and helpfull answer!